# Getting the new list after child is removed from Firebase Database

Tags: javascript, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

The documentation for `child_removed` states that the `DataSnapshot` passed into the callback will be the old data for the child that was removed.

I'm populating my database by calling `push` in another part of the code. Over here, I want to access the next value at the top of my database after the child at the top is removed. This is how I'm trying to do it but it's not working.

```
var ref = firebase.database().ref("Windsor boyss").limitToFirst(1);
    ref.on("child_removed", function(snapshot) {
        ref.once("value", function(snapshot) {
            snapshot.forEach(function(childSnapshot) {
                console.log("Child is ", childSnapshot.val);
            });
        });
    });
```

For example, when the child with username javedh is removed, the EventListener should get triggered and it should print `Child is tjaved` because that is the value at the top of the database after the child at the top is deleted.

[image]

Can anyone help me come up with an effective solution for this? Thanks!

Comment: It's not clear to me what you're trying to do.  Please edit the question to explain in more detail.  It will help if you illustrate with actual data.

Comment: @DougStevenson I've done then. Could you please take a look and see if it's clear now?

Comment: I think you'll just want to use a normal listener on `ref` to know when the query results change.

Comment: The normal listener gets triggered even when a child gets added. I want it to get triggered only when a child node is deleted.

Answer (score 0):

As Doug commented, using a nested listener on the same reference is pretty unusual.

The idiomatic way to to use `on("value"`, something like:

```
var ref = firebase.database().ref("Windsor boyss").limitToFirst(1);
ref.on("value", function(snapshot) {
    snapshot.forEach(function(childSnapshot) {
        console.log("Child is ", childSnapshot.val);
    });
});
```

---

**Update**: I think the problem may be coming from the fact that your `ref.once("value"` is being served from the local (in memory) cache of the snapshot, which as that point contains no data.

I was able to work around it by creating a new query to listen to inside the callback, instead of listening to the same query (what you call `ref`):

```
var ref = firebase.database().ref("Windsor boyss");
var query = ref.limitToFirst(1);
query.on("child_removed", function(snapshot) {
  console.log("Child "+snapshot.val()+" was removed");
  ref.limitToFirst(1).once("value", function(snapshot) {
    snapshot.forEach(function(childSnapshot) {
      console.log("First child is "+childSnapshot.val());
    });
  });
});
```

For the full working test bed, see: https://jsbin.com/feqojey/edit?js,console

Note that you were missing `()` after `val()` in the loop, but that wasn't the cause of the problem.

Comment: The "value" listener will get triggered when a child gets added as well. I only want the listener to show the next child at the top after the previous child at the top is deleted.

Comment: It doesn't print out anything.

Comment: I think I was able to reproduce the problem, and work around it. See the code in my answer and in the linked jsbin.

Comment: Thank you so much Frank. I'll give it a try!

Comment: Hey Frank. I upvoted your answer but Stackoverflow says "Thanks for the feedback! Votes cast by those with less than 15 reputation are recorded, but do not change the publicly displayed post score."

Comment: if you got it working based on my answer, there's also an accept button to indicate that. But I'd also just like to know if you got it working, as I spent considerable time trying to come up with something that would work for your use-case.

Comment: Yes it worked just fine, thank you so much. I did that.